# Acronym within acronym with glossaries

Tags: glossaries

I have been using an acronym within an acronym successfully with Texlive 2022 like so

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\newacronym{W}{W}{word}
\newacronym{S}{S}{sentence that contains a \gls{W}}

\begin{document}

This is a \gls{S}.

\end{document}
```

With Texlive 2022 this produces what I expect (and want):

> This is a sentence that contains a word (W) (S).

By contrast, Texlive 2023 produces this:

> This is a sentence that contains a word (W) (W).

I am wondering if there is an issue with Texlive 2023 and/or the version of the glossaries package that it ships, or whether I am using the nested `\gls{}` out of its scope. Either way I would like to know how to (properly) achieve the Texlive 2022 result with Texlive 2023.

(Note: I am doing this on Overleaf, where I can switch between Texlive versions, but need to make it work with Texlive 2023 specifically because I need to submit a paper to a repository that necessarily uses texlive 2023)

---

Edit: It seems that I can retrieve the intended behavior if I "protect" the command with extra curly brackets: `\newacronym{S}{S}{sentence that contains a {\gls{W}}}`... quite the obvious thing to try in retrospect...

Comment: You may want to post this on the bug tracker for the `glossaries` package, https://www.dickimaw-books.com/bugtracker.php?category=glossaries